# Opening an HTML page in a browser from Common Lisp

Tags: html, file, browser, lisp, common-lisp

My Common Lisp program writes out an HTML file.  I then want to launch this file in the user's default browser.

Is there a way of doing this in Common Lisp?  Moreover, is there an OS-independent way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the Common Lisp implementation and possibly the platform it runs on (Windows, Mac, Linux, ...).

LispWorks provides the function SYS:OPEN-URL. See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/LW/html/lw-1369.htm#pgfId-1219832

```
(sys:open-url "http://www.foo.com/")
```

One certainly can also use a file URL.

Answer (score 1):

No. That would be a pretty useful thing to do, so if you write code to do it portably, share!

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do it, but there is [a reasonably portable library](http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-shell/) that can execute shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

This project is the answer https://github.com/eudoxia0/trivial-open-browser.

TLDR;

You can use `uiop:run-program` for that. Argument will depend on the system that is running, e.g. on MacOS it is `"open http://www.example.com/"` (see https://github.com/eudoxia0/trivial-open-browser/blob/master/src/trivial-open-browser.lisp)